# How to solve Unexpected HTTP status code: 404(-1)

Tags: xcode, swift, http, github

Although I set up my xcode swift file to create a repository when I click SourceControl -> Make a Working Copy I receive the error window "All projects are already under source control. Then when I to Window -> Welcome to Xcode -> "Check out an existing project" I get the error "Unexpected HTTP status code: 404(-1). 
Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this please? Thank you

Comment: are you sure, that you're using a valid URL? `404` - means `Not found`.

Comment: Oh probably not, so https://github.com/username  would not be a valid url? @pivanchy

Comment: not sure, but I think you jyst need to add a protocol too(http or https)

Comment: Do not use the url from the browser's address bar .

Answer (score 6):

When you use `Welcome to XCode > Check out an existing project` you need to enter the github repository url as provided on the `<> Code` tab in github. It will look something like

```
    https://github.com/username/MyRepository.git
```

Comment: in my case i used the Url of the repository from the browser's address bar .Which was wrong

Comment: Comparing the browser's URL to the code URL, the difference is to be sure it starts with `https://` and ends with `.git`.  When I copied from browser, all I needed to do was add `.git` at end.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got -401 with the following premises:

- The URL was OK
- The user credentials were OK
- However, the user was not approved for downloading from that repository

Using the correct user solved the issue.

Comment: What's the correct permissions for it? I have `scope=repo`.. but couldnt see what else I might need.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when using xcode with bitbucket service.

Not entirely sure if I changed something or bitbucket changed something but I noticed that my domain in the URI for the remote had changed in bitbucket and xcode was no longer attempting to push to the correct path.

eg.

domain/repo.git

for some reason now was:

domaincom/repo.git

again, I do not remember changing anything but perhaps something changed in bitbucket to alter how the usernames are formed?

I think my team ( username ) was domain.com and they always worked with the first part up until the first . but perhaps changes have allowed for their service to remove all dots and use the full team name ( username )

I removed and re added the remote using the correct URI and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was with my bitbucket plan which had exceeded the free plan tier and was restricted to read-only. Fixed my plan in bitbucket, and the issue was solved after a while.